# Simple jquery ajax return

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, return

i have this simple script:

```
function paginateUsers(page){
   get( _config_remote_host+'/users?page='+page,function(json){

      json = JSON.parse(json);
        var _html = "";
        var json_users;
        var json_num_users;

        if(json.users){
        json_users = json.users;
        json_num_users = json.number_of_users;
        }
        if(!json.users){
            json_users = json;
            json_num_users = 0;
        }
        for(i = 0; i < json_users.length; i ++){
          if(i == 0){ _html += '<div class="row-fluid separator20">';}
          _html += '<div class="span3 media userbox">'
                      +'<div class="row-fluid">'
                       + '<div class="span3">'
                        + ' <a class="thumbnail" href="#">'
                         +' <img src="jon.png" alt=""/>'
                        +'  </a>'
                       +' </div>'
                        +'<div class="span9">'
                         +' <ul class="unstyled">'
                          +'  <li><strong><a href="user.html?id='+json_users[i].id+'">'+json_users[i].first_name+'</strong></br>'+json_users[i].last_name+'</a></li>'

                             +'   <li><h6>New york city</h6></li>'
                        +'    <li><a class="pull-right btn btn-mini">Contact</a></li>'
                       +'   </ul>'
                      +'  </div>'
                     +' </div>'
                    +'</div>';
                if(i%3 == 2){ _html += '</div><div class="row-fluid separator20">';}
             } 

        $('.users-list').html(_html).hide().fadeIn(100);
        //return always total users number to calculate total links number
        return json_num_users;
        });

  }
```

then i do

```
var n = paginateUsers(1);
    alert(n)
```

but it alerts always 'undefined' , what's the real problem here?

here the ajax call and init functs:

```
function createCORSRequest(_method, _url){
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
    // Check if the XMLHttpRequest object has a "withCredentials" property.
    // "withCredentials" only exists on XMLHTTPRequest2 objects.
    xhr.open(_method, _url, true);
  } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
    // Otherwise, check if XDomainRequest.
    // XDomainRequest only exists in IE, and is IE's way of making CORS requests.
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(_method, _url);
  } else {
    // Otherwise, CORS is not supported by the browser.
    xhr = null;
  }
  return xhr;
}

/*END INIT FUNCTION*/

function get(_url, _callback){
  var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET',_url);
  if (!xhr){
    throw new Error('CORS not supported');
  }
  $('.ajax-loading').show();
  xhr.send();

  /*SUCCESS -- do somenthing with data*/
  xhr.onload = function(){
    // process the response.
    _callback(xhr.responseText);
    $('.ajax-loading').hide();
  };

  xhr.onerror = function(e){
    console.log(e);
    $('.ajax-loading').show();
  };
}
```

thanks

Comment: You can't `return` from an AJAX call.  It doesn't work that way.

Comment: What is `get` function? Do you mean `$.get`?

Comment: Instead of using `JSON.parse`, just use `$.getJSON`.

Comment: @Rocket that really doesn't solves

Comment: It was just an FYI.  Also, you're already using jQuery, why are you doing `XMLHttpRequest` manually?  Why aren't you using jQuery's wonderful `$.ajax` and friends (it *should* support CORS)?

Comment: @Rocket cause of CORS problems using jquery

Comment: @VisioN check my edit please sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot return from an AJAX call, it's asynchronous.  Your return is inside the callback function, which runs at some point in the future, when the AJAX call is done.  `paginateUsers` doesn't actually return anything (which means it returns `undefined`).

Instead of trying to return anything, you should do all actions related to the data inside the callback.  Or, better yet pass a callback function, and call that when you're done.

```
function paginateUsers(page, callback){
    get( _config_remote_host+'/users?page='+page,function(json){
        // code...
        if(typeof callback === 'function'){
            callback(json_num_users); // Instead of "return json_num_users;"
        }
    });
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
paginateUsers(1, function(result){
    // result should be the value of json_num_users
});
```

Comment: @Ispuk: I mean what you want to do is impossible.  You cannot return the value.  You need put all code that uses the response inside the callback.  Or pass your own callback, see my edit.

Comment: but i'm putting all to the callback as function get (_url,_callback) .. what is wrong please?

Comment: @Ispuk: I mean pass a callback to the `paginateUsers` function instead of having it return anything.

Comment: you can make me crazy man, i just tryed ajax crossDomain and many others options for almost 4 hours of works, i just need to return that damn of json_num_users and i CAN'T use $.ajax $.post $.get $.getJSON $.damn ahahahahahah ))) really i'm not joking man

Comment: @Ispuk: I don't know much about CORS (have you tried JSONP instead, jQuery supports that), but the point is still that you cannot return the value.  The best you can do is pass a callback to `paginateUsers` and call that with `json_num_users`.

Comment: i can't use jsonp cause of web service standards @Rocket

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11031/discussion-between-ispuk-and-rocket)

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything from `paginateUser`, if you return result of `get`, which probably should be `$.get` you'll have deffered object (after jquery 1.5) which has methods like `done` `then` which accept corresponding callbacks as parameters

also you can do this

```
var p = $.get(....)  ( or $.post or $.ajax etc )

$.when(p).done(mydone).fail(myfail)

function mydone(data){  }
function myfail(err) {  }
```

EDITED: after your edits I see you are implementing ajax calls on your own, and using jquery for DOM manipulation , which is wierd

better just use `$.getJSON` method which accepts url and return deffered object , it is much more convineint to use and has solid API

Comment: i can't use jquery for ajax call cause of CORS problems sorry

Comment: @Ispuk: jQuery *should* support CORS.

Comment: also can't you just do it with jsonp ?

Answer (score 0):

$.get is running asynchron - it starts a new request to the server, which will return something when all the server side processing is done.

But your paginateUser() function is running inside the browser, it just sends the request (to nowhere/to the server) without waiting for the results.

Comment: please check better the json is returned and i use that to put data on html page, how can you say that there is no results please. ..

Comment: the callback is called when the server sends back the response - but then your javascript is already through. You have to understand, that a get method is something like a new process which is running with an own lifecycle - your javascript is not waiting for the servers response. debug it by using alert. then you will see, the callback function is called after the paginateUser function is over.